# Why swift app IPA crashes when I open the app ?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, crash

I have created app in Swift language and install that IPA (Distribution profile) on the my iPad, the app getting crash. But I run through debug mode its running correctly on the same device. Can you give the solutions for this crashing ? and How do I fix this issue ?

Xcode version : 6.3.1
iOS version : 8.3

Crash log in device :

```
Apr 26 23:12:46 My-iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[445] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0E13BE10-CBAC-45FF-AAB9-575F87B32216 (sandbox)
Apr 26 23:12:46 My-iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: TestApp(pid 445) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has no team identifier and is not a platform binary: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CFDED3C6-7AF6-427B-BBFC-27E9186EF590/TestApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Apr 26 23:12:46 My-iPad ReportCrash[411] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 445
Apr 26 23:12:46 My-iPad ReportCrash[411] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process TestApp[445]
Apr 26 23:12:46 My-iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.mobility.TestApp[0x3c28][445]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Apr 26 23:12:46 My-iPad SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image
Apr 26 23:12:47 My-iPad ReportCrash[411] <Notice>: Saved report to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TestApp_2015-04-26-231246_My-iPad.ips
Apr 26 23:12:47 My-iPad locationd[56] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Apr 26 23:12:47 My-iPad SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mobility.TestApp[0x3c28]' crashed.
Apr 26 23:12:47 My-iPad locationd[56] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: The second line of the log suggests the problem is a lack of a team identifier. Have you looked into that problem?

Comment: Also, it says "is not a platform binary", so you're probably putting a simulator build on the iPad.

Comment: @ThomasW, The app installing correctly but my problem is when I open the app it will crash. Why it will crash ?

Comment: @ManiApple The 2nd line of the log says that it did *not* install correctly.

Comment: @ericd, No... App installing and open up to splash screen then only getting crash. The debug mode its running correctly. So that I have confused lot.

Comment: Why don't you use Xcode to install the app?

Comment: @ThomasW, ericd... Please check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer after long time. We **should update our certificates and provision profiles** after iOS 8 release. Then only the swift apps will not crash. Please refer the following link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html